# not able to pass value to javascript function from jquery's success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling javascript function filename in success of jquery  as below , but i am not able to get p in javascript

```
    success: function(result) {
 var htmlString = [result];
        for (i = 0; i < htmlString.length; i++) {
            var p = htmlString[i].Number;
            $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a rel="' + p + 
                '" href="#" onclick="filename(p);" class="filePreview"></a></tr>');
        }
    }
```

how to get p in filename?

thanks,

michaeld

Comment: What is `htmlString`? Or is your problem `onclick="filename(p);"` (which is a problem too ;))?

Comment: sorry edited the question, problem is to pass p to javascript

Comment: You apear to be abusing [the rel attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-rel), it does not mean "Store arbitary data here", so don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
success: function(result) {
for (i = 0; i < htmlString.length; i++) {
                    var p = htmlString[i].Number;
                    $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a rel="' + htmlString[i].Number+ '" href="#" onclick="filename(' + p + ');" class="filePreview">/a></tr>');
            }
```

Comment: Works as long as `p` is a primitiv value (which is likely).

Comment: even it's not working may be with that syntax javascript is not taking any value passed.

Answer (score 1):

`htmlString` is an array of length one. There is no need to loop over it. It looks to me you could just do:

```
success: function(result) {
    $('<tr />').append(
        $('<td />', {
            rel: result.Number,
            href: '#',
            'class': 'filePreview',
            click: function() { filename(result.Number)}
        })
    ).appendTo('#MyGrid tbody');
}
```

Btw. if the `a` element does not contain any text, no one will be able to click the link.

---

Besides possible other possible mistakes/bad practices, why does `onclick="filename(p);"` not work?

The `p` you declared before is not in any scope that can is accessible when `filename(p)` is evaluated (on click). It is only local to the `success` handler. Writing the character `p` inside a string is totally unrelated to the variable `p` in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in the code, you're not closing the a-tag